# ng-tags-input custom template not working

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ng-tags-input

I am experiencing some troubles trying to get ng-tags-input to work.
I am trying to a custom template for my tags, and my code is barely what the developers show in the [demos](http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/demos). 
Everything works fine, except for the fact that my custom template is ignored (see the code below ).
Am I missing anything trivial? Why are tags still shown with the default template?

**Background**: App built in Angular (with routing), and Bootstrap. The code below is in one of Angular views.

**Code**:

```
 <div class="form-group">
      <label for="tags">Tags</label>
      <tags-input ng-model="tags" name="tags"
                        display-property="name"
                        id="tags"
                        template="tagtemplate">
          <auto-complete source="loadTags($query)"></auto-complete>
      </tags-input>

      <script type="text/ng-template" id="tagtemplate">
              <div class="tag-template">
                <span class="label label-info tag">
                  {{$getDisplayText()}}
                  <a class="remove-button" ng-click="$removeTag()">&#10006;</a>
                </span>
              </div>
      </script>
 </div>
```

Comment: could you create a plunkr with a reproducible issue? I can't reproduce the problem which you are facing

Comment: Are you using version 2.3.0?

Comment: @MichaelBenford It works with version 2.3.0. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then then answer is @MichaelBenford's comment. The code works fine with version 2.3.0.